# How to use decrypted AES key and execute php script with it's result

Tags: php

i currently have a php script that decrypt a password stored in mysql then connect to imap, so far the decryption works great, i can even echo the result and it does return the correct password but for some reason imap is not connecting..

here is what i have

```
$email_pass = $sql['EMAIL_PASS'];

//Decrypt Account password.

function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) {
$output = false;

$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
$secret_key = 'ksdkjdksdk';
$secret_iv = 'sdfdfdfdf';

// hash
$key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

// iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

if( $action == 'decrypt' ){
    $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
}

return $output;
}

$dec_pass = encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $email_pass);

echo $dec_pass; // this echo the correct password.


//connect to imap

$i = @imap_open("{{$server}:$port/$con_type}$eml_from", $account_uname, $dec_pass);
```

Imap is failing to connect. if i manually type in the password, it works. any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you `var_dump` the password as there might be some hidden white space in the string

Comment: i tried that no luck, i even tried stripping white spaces. still no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

I got this working, turns out that the code is fine, the mailbox account was locked on the server because of too many failed attempts when i was testing. :)..